# Java InputStreamReader & UTF-8 charset

Tags: java, utf-8, character, inputstreamreader

I use InputStreamReader to transfer compressed images. InflaterInputStream is used for decompression of images

```
InputStreamReader infis =
   new InputStreamReader(
      new InflaterInputStream( download.getInputStream()), "UTF8" );
do {
   buffer.append(" ");
   buffer.append(infis.read());
} while((byte)buffer.charAt(buffer.length()-1) != -1);
```

But all non-Latin characters become "?" and the image is broken http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1205/7c/9df90800fba5.gif

With the transfer of uncompressed images I use BufferedReader and everything is working fine

```
BufferedReader is =
   new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader( download.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: Image files are typically binary, why are you converting them to characters?

Comment: Where do I convert them? read() gives me the incorrect data (bytes 65533)

Comment: It looks like you're converting them when you say `buffer.append(" ")`

Comment: No, already when using `Reader/Writer`.

Answer (score 5):

Reader/Writer classes are designed to work with textual(character based) input/output.

Compressed images are binary, and you need to use either InputStream/OutputStream or nio classes for transferring binary data.

An example using InputStream/OutputStream is given below. This example stores the received data in a local file:

```
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {

        bis = new BufferedInputStream(download.getInputStream());
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\mylocalfile.gif"));

        int i;
        // read byte by byte until end of stream
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1) {
            bos.write(i);
        }
    } finally {
        if (bis != null)
            try {
                bis.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        if (bos != null)
            try {
                bos.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: The transfer of uncompressed binary images is working properly

Comment: gif - http://s019.radikal.ru/i602/1205/7c/9df90800fba5.gif All broken characters - 65533

Comment: gif is a compressed image format. What is the **uncompressed** image format you are using?

Comment: Gif image is compressed zlib, and I get it to a socket in a compressed form. I use it for illustrative purposes only, can be transferred any file formats

Comment: @Dimitry please don't get me wrong, but in the first comment (and in your question) you mention that Reader/Writers work for uncompressed binary images. So can you share what this uncompressed image format is. Could it be an ASCII format by any chance? For instance PPM, PGM, PBM, PNM formats can be in ASCII fomat. If that's the case, then we would have a good explanation. That's my point.

Comment: compressed images - means that the image in GIF format, compressed ZLIB library. uncompressed images - means that the image in GIF format, NOT compressed ZLIB library. What is unclear?

Comment: "use either InputStream/OutputStream" and I use that (download.getInputStream()) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream()

Comment: So you mean Uncompressed GIF format. The encoding of this format may be somehow "compatible" with UTF8 (at least not producing illegal byte values), I don't know.

Comment: Can you just try using BufferedInputStream, for instance, instead of BufferedReader, and avoid using Reader/Writers. That will definitely fix your issue.

Comment: What do you want to do with transferred image, store or display or something else? I can post a complete working code if you like.

Comment: The image will be stored. Maybe I'm wrong, but how do I properly write data to a StringBuilder? BufferedInputStream infis = new BufferedInputStream(new InflaterInputStream(download.getInputStream()));
 buffer.append(infis.read()); - It does not work (infis.read() return int) (char)(int)infis.read() - is also not correct. If no trouble, I will be grateful for the example

Comment: Your stream gives you binary data, and StringBuilder is a character oriented class. Why would you want to put binary data to StringBuilder? If for the sake of debugging/visualization you can convert each byte to hex string as explained here: http://www.coderanch.com/t/526487/java/java/Java-Byte-Hex-String

Comment: I can post some working code as promised, but can you tell me what the example code should do with the received image data? Is it OK if I just store the data in a local file?

Comment: file will be unpacked? (The stream with the image is packed with a zlib library). I use InflaterInputStream because I know exactly what size will be the output file. (i = bis.read()) != -1 - do not fit because after a file transfer connection is not interrupted. I do not know exactly how big the file in compressed form, and I do not know how many bytes I need to take in a condensed form.

Comment: No, the example code I posted stores the received data directly.

Comment: problems with obtaining the uncompressed data I do not have

Comment: @Dmitriy - maybe it hasn't been said explicitly enough, or has been lost in all the comments:  _there should be no Readers/Writers/Strings/StringBuilders/char[]s anywhere in this code_ (regardless of compressed/uncompressed status).  is should be InputStreams/OutputStreams/byte[]s all the way from network to disk.

Comment: @HakanSerce - btw, typically it's much faster to copy streams using a temporary byte[], not byte by byte.